# Input text with autocomplete - Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function in PHP, MySQL and jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to do a autocomplete text input in jQuery with user information from database in PHP and MySQL.
I'm getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function
at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (file.php:332)
at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2)
at HTMLInputElement.v.handle (jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2)
```

I import jQuery on header.php that is included in all pages:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This is my file.php which is the file with the script and the input, I'll leave just a part of the code, of course the input is inside a form

```
<input type="text" name="autor" id="autor" placeholder="Escreve o nome do autor" />
<div id="autorLista"></div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#autor').keyup(function() {
            var query = $(this).val();;
            console.log(query);

            if (query != '') {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "./components/search.php",
                    method: "POST",
                    data: {
                        query: query
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        $('#autorLista').fadeIn();
                        $('#autorLista').html(data);
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        $(document).on('click', 'li', function() {
            $('#autor').val($(this).text());
            $('#autorLista').fadeOut();
        });
    });
</script>
```

I don't even know if php code is working correctly but I think it is. I'll leave it below (search.php):

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['query'])) {
    $link = new_db_connection();
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($link);

    $output = '';

    $query = "SELECT id_user, nome_user FROM users WHERE nome_user LIKE ?";

    if (mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $query)) {
        $output = "<ul>";

        if (mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) > 0) {
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $nome_user);

            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

            mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id_user, $nome_user);

            if (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
                $output .= "<li>" . $nome_user . "</li>";
            }
        } else {
            $output = '<li>O utilizador que procura não existe.</li>';
        }
        $output .= "</ul>";
        echo $output;
    } else {
        echo 'erro';
    }
}
```

I've tried changing versions of jquery, checked the slim version, etc and nothing makes this work... Any idea, please? Any doubts or if I wasn't clear, just tell me please. Thank you!

Comment: The linked version of jQuery from the CDN, is not a slim version.  So what did you mean by "checked the slim version"?

Comment: Because I read that slim version had problems and I checked if the one I was using wasn't one of those, sorry @Taplar

Comment: Check your network tab and make sure you are importing only one version of jQuery

Comment: That's not helpful.  As CreeperMaxCZ pointed out, your stack trace shows the file the error originates from is a slim version, but that's not what you say you are including.  Which suggests your page is including multiple version of jQuery, which it should not be doing

Comment: It's loading the slim version from somewhere. See the last 2 lines of the error

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/MH2lakq here

Comment: Is this a wordpress site?

Comment: No @Taplar, I'm using bootstrap

Comment: You need to figure out why the slim version is being imported.  You can also try changing your document ready to `$(document).ready(function($) {` so it passes in the version if jQuery you made the ready with

Comment: If you're using a *nix/Mac, you can try `grep -R slim *` from the main project directory to see which, if any, files mention the slim version of jquery.

Comment: Damn it, thank you, it was from the line where I was importing bootstrap, bootstrap suggests slim version of jquery in its page

Comment: Now I get 500 (Internal Server Error) when writing on the input

Comment: That sounds like a different issue.  If your original issue is no longer present, i would suggest closing/deleting it and making a new one for your new issue

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59616803/500-internal-server-error-in-ajax-call-to-php-file @Taplar

Answer (score 1):

In your error it is showing you are using jQuery slim, which doesn't have Ajax.

> (jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2)

Please check you are using ONLY normal jQuery, not the slim version.

Comment: I see in Network tab the slim version but I'm not importing anything

Answer (score 0):

I was importing a slim version when importing bootstrap because it was suggested on their webpage.
Now I'm using this

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Instead of

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```